# Parsing online XML on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I have this [XML](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20local.search%20where%20query=%22sushi%22%0A%20%20%20and%20location=%22san%20francisco,%20ca%22%0A%20%20%20and%20Rating.AverageRating%3E4.0%0A&diagnostics=true) and I want to parse it to use in my WP app.

This is what I did:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        Uri url = new Uri("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20local.search%20where%20query%3D%22sushi%22%0A%20%20%20and%20location%3D%22san%20francisco%2C%20ca%22%0A%20%20%20and%20Rating.AverageRating%3E4.0%0A&diagnostics=true", UriKind.Absolute);
        client.OpenReadAsync(url);
    }


    public void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
            var query = from c in xml.Descendants("Query")
                        select new
                        {
                           ...
                        };
        }
        catch (Exception c)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
        }
    }
```

The problem is in this line:

```
var query = from c in xml.Descendants("Query")
```

Although I'm not missing any references...

Is this a good way to parse a XML?

Should I use LINQ to XML or `XmlReader`?

Comment: You say there's a problem, but you haven't said *what* the problem is. What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. This is giving me a nice list of Sushi bars far far away from my place:

```
public void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
        // get all the result rows from the query (they come as <Result> elements as child elements of <Results> which in turn is a child of <query>)
        var results = from row in xml.Element("query").Element("results").Elements().Where( element => { return (element.Name.LocalName == "Result"); } )
                      select row;

        // now I loop all rows and print the title; of course you can
        // do other stuff here or combine some data processing with the LINQ above
        // - this is up to you
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            XElement title = result.Elements().Where(element => { return element.Name.LocalName == "Title"; }).FirstOrDefault();
            if (title != null)
                Debug.WriteLine(title.Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception c)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
    }
}
```

(And if anybody knows a better way of dealing with these namespaces please enlighten me. I am using `LocalName` to bypass them.)

Comment: I've tried to use your example but I get an error when i try to put Elements().where...
The where doest not appear to me here, and even if I try to put only 
var result = from row in xml.Element("query").Element("results") 
                             select row;
it returns a error: Could not find a implementation of the query pattern for source type: 'System.Xml.Linq.Xelement'. select not found

Comment: I've figured out the problem!

Comment: I've figured out the problem! A reference to system.linq was missing...  So did the linq to xml code: 

XElement xml = XElement.Load(e.Result);
                var searched = from c in xml.Descendants("th")
                               select c;
                foreach (var item in searched)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(item.Value);
               }

Comment: Yep, you need this reference. Good that you figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ to XML is fine... but the URL you linked to only has a single query element, and it's `<query>`, not `<Query>`. It's not really clear what's going wrong for you, but changing to `xml.Descendants("query")` might be all you need...

Comment: What about the methods? Should I Use openReadAsync or DownloadStringAsync?  Link to xml has complained that It didnt find the xml in my .xap...

Comment: @DiegoVin: Why not just use `XDocument.Load(url)` to start with? If `e.Result` is a stream then I'd *expect* it to be okay... can you give the *precise* error message?

Comment: XDocument.Load does not load from web urls on Windows Phone. Personally - I used DownloadStringAsync, since it makes debugging easier but OpenReadAsync might work just as well.

Comment: @xyzzer: Interesting - I could have sworn I'd used `XDocument.Load(url)` from WP7. Maybe not...

Comment: @DiegoVin: No, this was a normal HTTP URL. I could be misremembering though.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see, when i tried to that here I got the error: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(string)' has some invalid argument

Comment: @DiegoVin: What were you trying to pass? It needs the url as a string rather than a Uri...

Comment: @JonSkeet I was passing an uri created before. uri = new uri(xml url)

Comment: It does not have an overload that takes a Uri. There is one for a string URI, but if you pass in a web URL you get:
Cannot open 'http://query.yahooapis.com/...'. The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.

Comment: They tried as hard as possible to make all operations that might be long running to only be exposed using the async pattern. They missed a few though, so you should still do things like parsing big XML files, doing isolated storage I/O or DB I/O asynchronously. I think WinRT goes further with that, so even parsing XML is only exposed asynchronously, but they can do that because it makes the resulting code sane thanks to the new async/await keywords.

Comment: @xyzzer: Yup, that makes a lot of sense.